# Jq: Select Key and Value of One Prop

Tags: json, jq

I have a json translation file that is structured like this.

```
{
  "STRING_ID_1": {
    "en": "Some englisch text.",
    "de": "Some german text."
  },
  "STRING_ID_2": {
    "en": "Some other englisch text.",
    "de": "Some other german text."
  },
  ...
}
```

Using this as input, I need to generate two files: "en.json" and "de.json". They should have the following format.

```
{
  "STRING_ID_1": "Some englisch text.",
  ...
}
```

and

```
{
  "STRING_ID_1": "Some german text.",
  ...
}
```

It seems to me that `jq` is the tool you want to use here. Can anyone provide me with the correct command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat file.json
{
  "STRING_ID_1": {
    "en": "Some englisch text.",
    "de": "Some german text."
  },
  "STRING_ID_2": {
    "en": "Some other englisch text.",
    "de": "Some other german text."
  }
}
$ jq 'with_entries(.value = .value.en)' file.json
{
  "STRING_ID_1": "Some englisch text.",
  "STRING_ID_2": "Some other englisch text."
}
$ jq 'with_entries(.value = .value.de)' file.json
{
  "STRING_ID_1": "Some german text.",
  "STRING_ID_2": "Some other german text."
}
```

Redirect to some other filename to save the output.

The transformation rewrites the value of each top-level key to be the value of the English (or German) string instead of an object of key-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you. I have an additional question: As it turns out, there are some ids that are only present in English. Currently they are stored with a `null` value. How do I simply omit them?

Comment: @PhilippSiegmantel `jq 'with_entries(.value = .value.en | select(.value != null))' file.json`  If I understand you correctly...